# Left adjoint to forgetful functor from graded algebra's

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

Does the forgetful functor from graded algebra's to algebra's have a left adjoint?

I was thinking the left adjoint would be something like $A\mapsto \prod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}A$, and when given $\phi:A\to Forget(B)$ we would define  $\phi_i:A\to B$ to be $\pi_i\circ\phi$. The inverse is problemetic though, because it should be something like $\{\phi_i\}\mapsto \sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}\phi_i$, but this doesn't make sense.

I'm also interested in the same question for $R$-modules instead of algebra's.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Consider how products look like in the category of graded algebras - does the forgetful functor preserve them?